# Log4net - Change file name based on logged user data

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I am trying to use this pattern to create a dynamic file name: "Debug_%property{LogUserName}.txt"

The value of %property{LogUserName} is retrieved from log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["LogUserName"], which is filled when the user logs in.

In the first time, it works perfectly. The file gets named like Debug_user1.txt (for example).

If user1 disconnects, and the user2 logs in (at the same browser) a new file should be created, but it's not happening.

It seems that the LogicalThreadContext.Properties are final variables, and can't be changed at runtime.

I tried to change the FileAppender.File property, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: How are you refreshing the configuration when the second user logs in? Also, if you change an Appender in code, you need to call it's ActivateOptions() method to activate the changes.

Comment: I tried to call XmlConfigurator.Configure() on every login, but it didn't work. I'll try to use the ActivateOptions() method. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this problem with stuartd's tip: calling ActivateOptions().